# YouTube integration in Titanium app?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

In my application I want to integrate YouTube to show videos. I want to retrieve the titles of the videos' thumbnails. I want to show thumbnails and video titles in a custom listview.

Is there a tutorial or code sample?

Comment: See this previous question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NYSenate App](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1-SBFGbnwLRSSG_oluaGsLw6FarO-QmnxzLxtgIap708) should be helpful.